# How to load huge aggregate (40+ tables, 500+ columns) from SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, orm, domain-driven-design

**Given**

Enterprise web application that uses SQL Server and Entity Framework for data access.

Domain model is a financial object hierarchy with about 40+ objects (in 40+ tables, 500+ columns), all together make an aggregate (as in DDD).

**Problem**

I need to load the whole aggregate at once. The root object and all the children, grandchildren, grand-grandchildren etc(depth is about 5 or 6)

I did not manage to find any way to efficiently load the aggregate using Entity Framework.

Options I tried:

1. Explicit loading - does too many calls
2. Eager loading - the SQL it generates is so ugly and not optimized for such a big aggregate so I think explicit loading with hundreds of calls would be faster
3. Muliple result set stored procedure + `objectContext.Translate`. Viable options. But when mapping the result to entities, the `DataAnnotation` are ignored (and we use underscore_casing for columns in db), resulting in massive duplication - each column the stored procedure returns needs to have a proper alias.

**Question**

Can somebody suggest what would be the most efficient and clean way to load the aggregate?

The load time should be a matter of ms, not seconds. As for the average object size - the aggregated serialized to JSON is usually below 100 kilobytes.

Any frameworks/micro-ORMs that can be of help here?

Comment: why dont write one store procedure in db?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to rethink your aggregate as it *really* should not be that large.

It may seem as though all the tables and other moving bits absolutely *have* to be together but in most cases it simply isn't true.  This is something that the navigation within the objects that an ORM produces may lead you to believe that they belong together.

Comment: joining in, nobody reads all that data. try to think how much they read in 1 page and make a SP for it with paging ect

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @EbenRoux, this really feels like the aggregate is far too large. 500 bits of information per aggregate is huge.

- Are you correctly modelling this in terms of invarients?
- Does the entire object graph need to change together and maintain consistency together?
- What are the business processes being modelled?

If it is really this big, you might want to look at alternative storage solutions:

- A document store would load this faster than a relational database if you stored the entire aggregate as a single document.
- You could do a hybrid approach using something like PostgreSQL which has native support for json whilst still being relational.
- Denormalize the data - optimise for reads over writes